# Is there a way to get this by .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my site root directory. there are donghua.php and index.php. now, is there a way to use `.htaccess` file to let the visitor access my site .the default shows `example.com/donghua.php`. not `example.com/index.php`. thank you. the server is Apache.

ps:The user still can access `example.com/index.php`

i using `DirectoryIndex donghua.php` in the .htaccess. the default page is ok. but when i access `example.com/index.php` it redirect to `example.com/donghua.php`. if i forbid it redirect how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the virtual host config file (or you should even be able to do this in htaccess) you can set the DirectoryIndex to be donghua.php if you want, i.e. instead of something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php default.html
```

Just do:

```
DirectoryIndex donghua.php
```

So whenever someone goes to your website, example.com, your apache installation will read donghua.php as the default index file.

Comment: i tired your code, the default page is ok. but i still want to i can access http://www.example.com/index.php

Comment: when i access example.com/index.php  it always redirect to example.com/donghua.php

Answer (score 0):

Change your redirection rule in .htaccess file for index.php. If you open the .htaccess file, you can find the follwing lines,

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/example.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)example.php$ http://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Change or remove this rule for index.php. Better remove or comment it then it won't redirect to another page

"RewriteCond" this code check the codition if the browser requesting the file name index.php. If the condition is satisfy, then the next line will execute that is "RewriteRule". This "RewriteRule" will redirect your URL.

Search and find the name "index.php" in .htaccess file. comment out that lines. syntax to comment is "#".

Example:

#RewriteCond

#RewriteRule

Take back up before changing anything in .htaccess file.

Comment: i don't know how to do?could you give it more clearly. thank you

Comment: "RewriteCond" this code check the codition if the browser requesting the file name index.php. If the condition is satisfy, then the next line will execute that is "RewriteRule". This "RewriteRule" will redirect your URL.

Search and find the name "index.php" in .htaccess file. comment out that lines. syntax to comment is "#".

Example:
#RewriteCond
#RewriteRule

Take back up before changing anything in .htaccess file.

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)donghua.php$ http://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L] i put this code in, but it not work

Comment: Remove the lines which associated with index.php and run the site

Answer (score 0):

**To make your URL lovely and suitable for search engine ranking.**

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.html HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**To redirect**

```
redirect 301 /old-page.php http://www.yoursite.com/new-page.php
```

Comment: Please visit at this link
http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/